# swapping three numbers using xor in a single line

Tags: algorithm, xor

I read that three variables a,b, and c can be swapped using the single statement below:
c = a ^ b ^ c ^ (a=b) ^ (b=c)

Similarly, two variables a and b can be swapped as:
a = a ^ b ^ (b=a)

Can somebody please explain how does this work?

P.S. Here is the link saying so.
http://p--np.blogspot.ro/2011/04/reverse-linked-list-using-only-2.html

Comment: Decompose as b= a; a= a ^ b ^ a;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make in the original statement all assignments (except the one you want to change to) are countered:

```
a = a ^ b ^ c ^ (b=c) ^ (c=a);
```

You assign `c=a`, `b=c`. The return value of those is `a` and `c` respectevely, so, you want to "counter" `a` and `c`, and you use the fact that `a^a == 0` and `c^c == 0`, and just add a,c at the beginning.

In addition, you add a `b`, to assign `a` to the value of `b`.

[Here is a demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/hQFIti)

Note that as discussed in comments, it is language dependent if the above is guaranteed to succeed or not. In Java, for example - [it is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7): `The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.`, while in others, such as C, it is not.

Comment: Order of operand evaluation is unspecified. `c=a` could be evaluated before `b=c`, and both can be evaluated before `b` or `c`.

Comment: @n.m. I need to re-verify it, but if I remember correctly, it is specified in java, for example.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, [15.7. Evaluation Order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7): `The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.`

Comment: It may be true in java, but a lot of languages don't guarantee this, namely, C and C++.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalvesc I added a clarification for it, but since we are discussing algorithms, and no language tag was specified, I believe that the algorithmic principle behind the idea is the important issue, and not the lack of definitions of specific languages. Anyway, you are right - and the fact that it is language dependent should be explicitly mentioned (edited).

Comment: @amit you are right, no language is specified, didn't notice that at first.

Comment: Since no language is specified, here's one in python: `a,b,c=b,c,a^0`.

Comment: @n.m. feel free to add it as an answer if you think it fits as a good answer for a question that is tagged as 'algorithm'. The main aspect of this question is understanding the algorithmic principle, IMO.

Comment: @amit I don't see how the question as it stands admits reasonable answers. Understanding algorithmic principles has nothing to do with doing it in one line. Lines are best discussed in context of programs written in specific languages. I have no idea what is a line of an algorithm.